# Using a constant random variable in a randomly generated component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a solar system app that automatically generates stars. My `star`s are a React component that accept a couple of props. When the user clicks the star, I need the `system` state to update and also I want the `navlink` to point to the same value.

```
let randomTypeVariable = starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)];
      return (
        <NavLink
          to={`/${randomTypeVariable}`}
          onClick={() => props.setSystem(`${randomTypeVariable}`)}
          className="starWrapper"
        >
```

However at the moment the `to=` prop and the `onClick` function are giving different results. I know that this is because the `randomTypeVariable` is running each time and giving different results.

These components are being randomly generated so I cannot have the variable be a constant value.
How can I assign both of these properties to be the same randomly generated variable?

For context here is the full `star` component

```
let randomTypeVariable = starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)];
  const makeStars = (Count = 5) => {
    if (Count > 0) {
      return (
        <NavLink
          to={`/${randomTypeVariable}`}
          onClick={() => props.setSystem(`${randomTypeVariable}`)}
          className="starWrapper"
        >
          <Star
            starName={`${makeStarName()}`}
            starPosition={positionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)]}
            starType={`${starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 2)]}`}
          ></Star>
          {makeStars(Count - 1)}
        </NavLink>
      );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't give a different result as `randomTypeVariable` is not a function, I tried this also.

Maybe I am missing something but still `useMemo` can solve your problem

```
const makeStars = (Count = 5) => {
    let randomTypeVariable = useMemo(() => starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)], []);
    if (Count > 0) {
      return (
        <NavLink
          to={`/${randomTypeVariable}`}
          onClick={() => props.setSystem(`${randomTypeVariable}`)}
          className="starWrapper"
        >
          <Star
            starName={`${makeStarName()}`}
            starPosition={positionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)]}
            starType={`${starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 2)]}`}
          ></Star>
          {makeStars(Count - 1)}
        </NavLink>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. Sorta. Now the `randomtypevariable` is the same  with every component. So I am getting 3-5 of the same type of star. Is there a way to preserve the randomness for each component?

Comment: can you please elaborate? what do you exactly mean when you say "preserve the randomness"?

Comment: In this method the `randomTypeVariable` is the same for all of the components. Example: it will return five `red`  instead of five different colors

Comment: In that case, you can declare randomTypeVariable in the parent component and pass it down through props

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to solve this as much as get around it.
The first thing I did was remove the `onClick` from my component

```
let randomTypeVariable = starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)];
    if (Count > 0) {
      return (
     
        <NavLink
          to={`/${randomTypeVariable}`}
          
          className="starWrapper"
        >
          <Star
          
            starName={`${makeStarName()}`}
            starPosition={positionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)]}
            starType={`${randomTypeVariable}`}
          ></Star>
          {makeStars(Count - 1)}
        </NavLink>
```

And considering I was still able to use the navigation path of `to={/${randomTypeVariable}}` I was able to gather the information I needed from the URL of the page instead of the state.

```
let url = window.location.href
    let modifiedUrl = url.split('/')
    props.setSystem(modifiedUrl[3])
```

At last, the randomly generated components are consistent. However this is more of an avoiding the problem than actually solving it. If anyone has an actual solution please let your voice be heard here.